# How to emit event from child to parent using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I use ngx-translate to make a multilingual web in angular. I use JSON files for languages and place them in assets / i18n / en.json (for english language) and assets / i18n / ge.json for german language. I implemented EventEmit event from child to parent as follows:

**child.component.ts :**

```
private translateService: TranslateService;
@Output() showLanguage = new EventEmitter();

constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService = translateService;
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
  }



 switchLanguage(language: string) {
    this.showLanguage.emit(this.translateService.use(language));
  }
```

**Child.html**

```
  <button (click)="switchLanguage('en')">en</button>
  <button (click)="switchLanguage('fr')">fr</button>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
private translateService: TranslateService;
 constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService = translateService;
  }
switchLanguage(language) {
    this.translateService.use(this.language);
 }
```

**Parent.html**

```
  <child-page (showLanguage)="switchLanguage($event)"><child-page>
```

**App.module.ts**

```
 export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
  }

  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

But when i click button angular throw me error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at TranslateService.use (ngx-translate-core.js:555)
    at ChildComponent.switchLanguage (childcomponent.component.ts:40)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ChildComponent.html:12)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at eval (core.js:10629)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
```

Please help me. Thank

Comment: parent component should at least be `this.translateService.use(language);` (I assume) instead of `this.translateService.use(this.language);`

Comment: I fail to see the point of all this. What are you trying to achieve? What's the point of changing the language a second time in the parent every time you change the language in the child?

Comment: @JB Nizet
Because my child component is the nav bar and the parent component is the Overview page. I'm currently putting buttons on the navbar.

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes i had edit but not work

Comment: So what? Once you've changed the language in the global, singleton translate service in the child, it's set, globally. Setting it again in the parent component is useless.

Comment: @tbtrungit Yes, I didn't look too closely at the question, I just noticed that on first glance :)

Comment: @AJT_82
Example: I have  **<h1>SomeContent<p>**  in parent. I want translate it from English to Germany by clicking on button  <button (click)="switchLanguage('ge')">ge</button> . 
How can I achieve that if I put that button in the nav bar? navbar.component is the child component of Overview

Comment: Well, as I said already, you just change the language, once, from anywhere you want. The service is a singleton, and once you set the language in the service, it's set, globally, for all components.

Comment: @JB Nizet
Does that mean I do not need EventEmit in the child component anymore? 
After I click on the button will make all changes right

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: @JBNize  When I fix it error  
**ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at TranslateService.use (ngx-translate-core.js:555)** still exist. How to fix it.

Comment: You'e probably using a version of ngx-translate that is incompatible with the version of Angular you're using. Check your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. I had downgrade version ngx-translate and it working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
switchLanguage(language: string) {
this.showLanguage.emit(this.translateService.use(language));
}
```

Try emitting the language only

```
switchLanguage(language: string) {
this.showLanguage.emit(language);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But as @JB Nizet said. We don't need EmitEvent from child to parent because language service is globally. Just set in child.